# watermelonDb: how pass array of string as a column type in schema?

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, schema, watermelondb

i want to set type of serverNames as a array of string but in watermelon it supports only boolean, string and number ,anybody help me over this

```
    export const settingSchema = tableSchema({
  name: 'SETTINGS',
  columns: [
    { name: 'serverId', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'server', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'base_url', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'serverNames', type: 'string', },//<-----serverNames,type:'[string]
    { name: 'amberIcon', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'showAllResident', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'showAllTask', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'filterStart', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'filterEnd', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'searchedText', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'currentTab', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'appInit', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'performRefresh', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'slowMessageDisplay', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'backgroundListener', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'displayResidentHeader', type: 'boolean' },
    { name: 'currentResident', type: 'string', isOptional: true },
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a json field type for that I believe. https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Advanced/AdvancedFields.html#json